# Modify Default <x-dropdown> size in Laravel Splade

Tags: laravel

Good day, is there a way to increase the width of the 'content' in this default laravel splade x-dropdown component?

```
<x-dropdown placement="bottom-end" width="w-100">
    <x-slot name="trigger">
        <button class="flex items-center text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white hover:text-gray-700 focus:outline-none transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
            <img class="w-8 h-8 rounded-full" alt="Profile Pic" src="">
        </button>
    </x-slot>

    <x-slot name="content">
        <div class="px-4 py-3" role="none" >
            <p class="text-sm text-gray-900 dark:text-white" role="none">
               {{ Auth::user()->name }}
            </p>
            <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 truncate dark:text-gray-300" role="none">
               {{ Auth::user()->email }}
            </p>
        </div>

        <x-dropdown-link :href="route('profile.edit')">
            {{ __('Profile') }}
        </x-dropdown-link>

        <!-- Authentication -->
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
            @csrf
            <x-dropdown-link as="a" :href="route('logout')" onclick="event.preventDefault(); this.closest('form').submit();">
                {{ __('Log Out') }}
            </x-dropdown-link>
        </form>
     </x-slot>
</x-dropdown>
```

[Profile Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49cEl.png)

I have tried the width="w-100" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your content with a div and adjust its width using Tailwind's width utility classes:

```
<x-slot name="content">
    <div class="w-64"> //adjust at here
        // ....
    </div>
</x-slot>
```

Comment: @RCDP, so you should click approve answer to show other users that question already handled.